# How to adjust the size of my figure here?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am working on a Page here for school.

I don't know how i can adjust the size of my figures Schutzklasse 1-3 with their Text. If you Zoom the text gets smaller but the basic picture not.

You dont need everything in the CSS because i have more pages. I just need help on my main page.

I tried things like width or margin and text align but it didn't work. I don't know what to do then.

I hope u can help me.

```css
figure,
figcaption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(7em, 1fr));
  gap: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#gallery figure {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#gallery>figure>figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.1em;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#gallery>figcaption {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

#gallery>figure>figcaption {
  opacity: 0.4;
  bottom: -3em;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

#gallery>figure:hover>figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: -2em;
}

.m1 {
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.img1 {
  float: right;
}

.m1::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.img1 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.ans1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.a1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

body {
  color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1.0);
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.825);
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

b {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Der VDE Guide</h1>
<p> </p>
<h3>Bitte wählen Sie eine der Schutzklassen:</h3>
<div class="gallery">
  <figure id="gallery">

    <figure>
      <a href="messungSK1.1.html">
        <img id="sk1" src="schutzklasse1.png">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a href="messungSK2.1.html">
        <img id="sk2" src="schutzklasse2.png">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a href="messungSK3.1.html">
        <img id="sk3" src="schutzklasse3.png">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 3</figcaption>

    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you exactly want? explain this I don't know how i can adjust the size of my figures Schutzklasse 1-3 with their Text. If you Zoom the text gets smaller but the basic picture not.

Comment: I couldn't really get your question. If I am correct, you you want it so that when you hover over the image, the image should get smaller?

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: I agree that the question isn't clear enough. Apart from that, I noticed that in your CSS you wrote `gap: 10%;` which should be `grid-gap: 10%;`

Comment: noo i just want that when you use CRTL+ Mouseup or Mousedown to Zoom that then the 3 figures also adapt to the size like all the other text

Answer (score 0):

[Ctrl-MouseScroll] or [Ctrl+]/[Ctrl-] (browser functionality) act differently compared to resizing the browser. Using the [Ctrl] zooming functions, the browser will act as if it is a different (larger/smaller) device, while resizing the the browser window just changes the available space on the given device (for now, I'm assuming your development desktop PC). This means that when you deeply zoom-in you are essentially looking at a very large smartphone.

With your CSS `img {...width: 100%... }` you want to scale the images to fill the maximum of the available space (on a very large smartphone), while you want the zooming to literally resize them. I don't know the technical specifics behind this, but you simply cannot have both.

So you need to choose either *resize to fit* and discard the zooming, or *enable zooming* and leave out the `img {...width: 100%... }` and replace it with:

```
figure img {
    display: block;     /* removes unwanted space below (default 'inline') */
    object-fit: cover;  /* resize and clip when too large (change to your needs) */
    max-width: 100%;    /* dont' go outside parent ('overflow: hidden' won't work) */
    margin: 0 auto      /* center horzontally in parent */
}
```

I have created a snippet with your code in which I added my solution, but also changed/simplified a few things:

- for clarity removed unused CSS
- also for clarity, moved EYE-CANDY only properties to their own section. Less optimized, but more clear CSS for the demo.
- heavily commented CSS where applicable
- you used `<figure>`s inside a `<figure>`, while totally legal, it unnecessarily complicated the structure of `.gallery`. I removed the *extra* layer.
- changed the original `grid-template-columns 3` to `auto-fit` so the grid nicely wraps when the viewport becomes too narrow.
- corrected the `gap` error to `grid-gap`
- changed the `.gallery` margins to `padding` and used `margin` to horizontally center `.gallery`
- changed `background` to `background-color` where applicable. While `background` is legal, it is also a *shortcut property* for various background settings. This becomes particularly important when you want to blend/mix `background-color` with `background-image`. In specific cases `background` overrides one of them (depending on how you defined the CSS) obfuscating a nice little bug that could keep you busy for a while. Just get used to using `background-color`.

**Do try out `<body outlines="1">`** as you will learn from the output that you have overlapping elements issues that might need to be addressed!

**And** the zooming now works as you want...

**The snippet**

```css
/* for debugging */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dotted }

figure,figcaption { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

figure img {
    display: block;     /* removes unwanted space below (default 'inline') */
    object-fit: cover;  /* resize and clip when too large (change to your needs) */
    max-width: 100%;    /* dont' go outside parent */
    margin: 0 auto      /* center horzontally in parent */
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(7em, 1fr)); /* changed 3 to 'auto-fit' */
  /* original 7em, now in pct of 1920 (average desktop) => 7 * 16 / 19.2 */

  grid-gap: 10%; /* MOD, was 'gap' */
  text-align: center;

  padding: 0 10%; /* 10% L/R space */  
  margin: 0 auto  /* center in parent */
}

.gallery figure {
  position: relative;

  /* some spacing after wrap */
  margin-bottom: 2em; /* modify to your needs */
}

.gallery>figure>figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.1em;

  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

  bottom: -3em; opacity: 0.4;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.gallery>figure:hover>figcaption {
  bottom: -2em; opacity: 1;
}

/******************/
/* EYE-CANDY only */
/******************/
.gallery figure {
  color: black; background-color: white;
}
.gallery>figure>figcaption {
  color: white; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

body {
  color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1.0); background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.825);
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

h3 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body outlines="0">

<h1>Der VDE Guide</h1>
<p> </p>

<h3>Bitte wählen Sie eine der Schutzklassen:</h3>

<div class="gallery">
    <figure>
      <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="messungSK1.1.html">
        <img id="sk1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/DC143C/FFF8DC?text=schutzklasse1">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="messungSK2.1.html">
        <img id="sk2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/7CFC00/000000?text=schutzklasse2">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="messungSK3.1.html">
        <img id="sk3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/6495ED/FFF8DC?text=schutzklasse3">
      </a>
      <figcaption>Schutzklasse 3</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
    
</body>
```